# emit signal doesnt connect to slot in another object

Tags: c++, qt, signals-slots

I am trying to connect   asignal from object of one  class into  slot of  another class but it doesnt work.

Description : I have a project with main window and lots of sub dialog windows . 
I am interested in sending some messages from sub dialog windows to main window.

SO for that I have created a class called sms_list.  The code in that class should add message into multi-set and send  the signal to pmainwindow . The PmainWindow is supposed to catch the signal into slot . But when I have debugged it I found that it emit the signal from sms_list but actually it fails to connect teh slot.
sms_list.h

```
#include <QString>
#include <QObject>
#include <QWidget >   
#include <set>
 class SMS_list:public QObject
{

   Q_OBJECT

  class LessSMSTime
     {
    public:
          /** Returns TRUE if the left time component is less than the right time
            * component
            */
            bool operator ()( const SMS& left, const SMS& right ) const;
   };

    typedef std::multiset<SMS, LessSMSTime> SMSSet

    public:

    SMS_list( PMainWindow* dialog_main )

    void add( const SMS& sms ); //SMS  is an object of another class called SMS

    //some other functions

   signals:

   void display_msg_up();

   private:
    // some private functions 
    PMainWindow*    dialog_main_;
    SMSSet          sms_;
};
```

sms_list.cpp

```
#include "Message_list.h"

Message_list::Message_list( PMainWindow* dialog_main )
: dialog_main_( dialog_main )
{

}


void SMS_list::add(const  SMS& sms )
{
 QMutex mutex;
  mutex.lock();
   // some more codes ..


sms_.insert( sms );// sms_ is a multi set

 emit display_msg_up();//signal to connect to slot on main window
mutex.unlock();
 }
```

PMainWindow.h

```
class  PMainWindow : public QDialog, private Ui::PMainWindow
{
   Q_OBJECT

public:
    PMainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);

// some more declarations

public slots:
  // some more slots
  void on_add_msg();// to add messages on QTable widget 

private:

// some more variable dec
SMS_list*                    sms_list_;

}
```

PMainWindow.cpp

```
PMainWindow::PMainWindow(QWidget *parent)
    : QDialog(parent), 
       // some other variable
       sms_list_( 0 )
{

  ui.setupUi( this );
  init_cal_signals();

  // some more function called  

}
void PMainWindow::init_cal_signals()
{

   sms_list_ = new SMS_list( this );
  connect( sms_list_, SIGNAL(  sms_list_->display_msg_up( ) ) ,  this , SLOT ( on_add_msg()  ) ); 

}

void PMainWindow::on_add_msg()
{

 qDebug() <<" Sadly code has not reached here .. " ;


}
```

Any Suggestions/criticisms are  most welcome.
thanks

Comment: In your connect line: `SIGNAL(  sms_list_->display_msg_up( ) )` This is not valid. The `SIGNAL` macro expects a **signature** (without instance name!) which will be resolved during runtime (that's why you don't see a compiler error). Didn't you get a warning printed that there is no such signal (during runtime)?

Comment: @leemes, Thanks mate for replying ,  I have tried something like SIGNAL( display_msg_up() ) bla bla  and it doesnt work , so while googling , I have seen something like this  so I just put that in a hope that magically it might work .. but it doesnt... So in short I have tried both syntax ..

Comment: Did / can you verify the following things: 1. Is the `emit` statement really executed? (Place a qDebug near it.) - 2. Is the connect statement returning true? (Q_ASSERT the returned bool.) - 3. As soon as the signal is emitted, is there really a slot connected? (Since Qt 5.0 there is [`QObject::isConnected`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtcore/qobject.html#isSignalConnected) which you can call just before / after the emit statement to check this.)

Comment: @leemes,  1. is the emit statement really executed ? Yes ,, because I have used debug statment stepinto/stepover  in VS2010( Actually I m using Qt plugin in vs2010) and stepinto /stepoer did actaully hit the emit code line.  2 Q_Assert-> You want me to add that in  init_cal_signals()?  q3)  As soon as the signal is emitted, is there really a slot connected? How would I know if emit signal actually connects to the slot? I guess this is my problem as I have no idea whether it is connected or not.

Comment: (By the way: you inherit from the generated UI class but in the constructor I see `ui.setupUi(this)` which is only correct if you have a `ui` member, but not if you inherit. If you accidentally both inherit *and* have a member that would be a bad thing. Please check this.)

Comment: Neither the signal nor the slot *connect* themselves. Some other code does (in your case the function `init_cal_signals`, which is neither a signal nor a slot). Once you emit a signal, Qt internally calls connected slots for you. To check *if any* slot is connected, use `QObject::isConnected`, see the link in my last comment (only in Qt 5 available). But first check if the connection is successful. For this, debug or assert the returned bool of the connect statement itself. Note that connect is simply a function call? It returns a bool, and this tells you if it was successful.

Comment: As pointed out the SIGNAL macro is wrong, also when do you expect emit to be called on this signal? Seems like you have threads so may not work as expected